# Создание и открытие нового окна в qt designer при нажатии на виджет menu action

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

Как в qt designer создать еще одно окно и связать его с главным окном путем нажатия на виджет: например из верхнего menu action  или  при нажатии на виджет button в главном окне должно открываться новое окно поверх предыдущего?

Comment: я бы вам посоветовал не пытаться все что нужно и не очень нужно реализовывать только в Qt Designer. Создайте форму/формы в Qt Designer.  Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения. И уже в этом созданном другом классе прописывайте логику какую пожелаете.

Comment: Если задача состоит в том, чтоб в новом окне ввести какие-то исходные данные, то можно пойти по пути добавления Tab Widget и там реализовать меню "Настройки". Это наверное самый простой способ. А уж потом, со временем, когда будет рабочий прототип,  когда появятся новые знания, можно перепаяться.  Сам иду по такому пути. Ну, если я не прав, специалисты меня поправят

Comment: Но если надо именно новое окно, то ответ найду, просто пока не хватает времени разбираться

Comment: Victor Karobchyc! Когда поднимите репутацию, не забудьте проголосовать за мои ответы. Их уже 3.

Answer (score 0):

Всплывающее окно реализовано для вкладки "Программирование". Представлены несколько вариантов. Нужно раскомментировать любой из трех.

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("template1.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('New')

        self.action.triggered.connect(self.exit_action)
        self.action_4.triggered.connect(self.dialog_btn_clicked)

        # Свойство автоповтора отключено по умолчанию, поэтому включаем его
        self.pushButton.setAutoRepeat(True)
        # Установка интервала 500 миллисекунд
        self.pushButton.setAutoRepeatInterval(500)
        # Вводим нужное число для начала отсчета. Я использовал 0
        self.counter = 0
        # Добавляем действие к кнопке
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.upClicked())

    def dialog_btn_clicked(self):
        # Реализованы несколько вариантов вывода окон. Нужно раскомментировать один из вариантов
#        res = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Привет!', 'Всем привет!')  # 1 вариант (статический медод)

#        res = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Пишем', 'Что-то пишем')       # 2 вариант (статический медод)
#        if res == QMessageBox.Yes:                                      # 2 вариант
#            QMessageBox.information(self, 'ДА', 'Вася нажал ДА')        # 2 вариант
#        elif res == QMessageBox.No:                                     # 2 вариант
#            QMessageBox.information(self, 'НЕТ', 'Вася нажал НЕТ')      # 2 вариант

        mess = QMessageBox()                                             # 3 вариант (динамический метод)
        mess.setText('Что-то пишем')                                     # 3 вариант
        mess.setDetailedText('Еще что-то пишем')                         # 3 вариант
        # mess.setIcon(QMessageBox.information)                          # 3 вариант   # Закоментировал строку с иконкой. Почему-то выдает ошибку
        mess.setWindowTitle('Внимание!')                                 # 3 вариант
        mess.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)     # 3 вариант
        mess.exec_()                                                     # 3 вариант
#        print(res)                                                      # для 1 и 2 вариантов

    def upClicked(self):
        self.label_4.setText(str(self.counter))
        self.counter += 1

    def exit_action(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***template1.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>970</width>
    <height>734</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Deqart</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>420</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>125</width>
      <height>160</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 75 72pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>▲</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>420</x>
      <y>400</y>
      <width>125</width>
      <height>160</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 75 72pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>▼</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>200</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>160</width>
      <height>125</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 75 72pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>◀</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>600</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>160</width>
      <height>125</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 75 72pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>▶</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>360</x>
      <y>310</y>
      <width>50</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>25</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>OX</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>550</x>
      <y>310</y>
      <width>50</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>25</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>OX</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>460</x>
      <y>350</y>
      <width>50</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>25</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>OY</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>460</x>
      <y>260</y>
      <width>50</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>25</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>OY</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>970</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Файл</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="action"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Настройки</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="action_2"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu_2">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Программирование</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="action_4"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu_3">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Помощь</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menu"/>
   <addaction name="menu_2"/>
   <addaction name="menu_3"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="action">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Выход</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_2">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Настройки</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_4">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Диалоговое окно</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, а если нужно чтобы в новом окне  был аналогичный menubar, как его реализовать в новом окне? Я так понимаю в ваших примерах реализация нового окна написана кодом, а не в дизайнере?

Comment: @Victor Karobchyc Здравствуйте! Я тоже только учусь. Мой совет вам сейчас научиться пользоваться поисковиком. Не поленитесь, посмотрите на ютубе как делают результативный поиск. Ищите по регионам Pdf книги. не знаете иностранные языки - не проблема, яндекс любые книги переведет. Ищите курсы на торренте. Ищите даже материалы по PyQt4, там тоже можно многое подчерпнуть. Сам иду по такому пути. Чем лучше осуществляется поиск - тем меньше вопросов на форуме, тем быстрее идет обучение

Comment: @Victor Karobchyc Напишите мне на почту nicenterst@mail.ru, поделюсь материалами, какие есть уже у меня